# Table column max-width, ellipsis, nowrap : not working in IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Why does the column get correctly cutoff with ellipses at 100px width in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE?

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100px;max-width:100px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap">QWRQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/66hvN/)

Comment: table-layout:fixed is suppose to work with width and for <table> basicly, here you dispatch width and table-layout onto 2 elements, that can be enough to confuse IE. ... Do you use a real standalone IE9 for test and in standard mode ?

Comment: This is working ie10, ie9, ie8 on a Windows7. Your problem is elsewhere in your coding.

Comment: Isn't IE in Quirks Mode or some Compatibility mode?

Comment: I am seeing this same bug aswel on IE9, good workaroound by the way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed by adding a div container and applying all the styles to it, instead of the < td > like so:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr>
        <td><div style="width:100px;max-width:100px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap">QWRQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWEEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWE</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```